# Pull code from git repo , in the startup script of a template of instance group

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

I am setting up a python app on GCP's instance group.

Due to some limitations , the app can not be deployed on cloud run and kubernetes. It has to be on
instance group.

1. How can I deploy the instance group with a new template , every time a code is pushed to a certain branch on github.
   Can I achieve that using cloud build?
2. If i want to create a startup script in a template , that will pull code from Github, how can i manage git password there , in the GCP's template's startup script?

We can SSH between instance and github to avoid password prompt. Can we define in the template , that we want to setup SSH between all the instances , that will be created using this template?

Answer (score 2):

> Due to some limitations, the app can not be deployed on cloud run and
> kubernetes. It has to be on instance group.

The reasons why might help generate better answers.

> How can I deploy the instance group with a new template, every time a
> code is pushed to a certain branch on GitHub. Can I achieve that using
> cloud build?

That would require writing custom code that Cloud Build runs. A better solution is to tell the MIG to replace all instances. The startup script will then pull down the latest code.

> If I want to create a startup script in a template, that will pull
> code from Github, how can I manage git password there, in the GCP's
> template's startup script?

Configure a customer VM instance with required software and GitHub SSH key pairs (not passwords). Create an image of the instance. Use that image in the instance template.

Create a startup script that pulls from GitHub on VM startup and configures the application. I do this type with Laravel and .NET.

Advice: Management Instance Groups mean that your instances should be stateless, be prepared to be replaced at any time, etc. Your strategy goes against that philosophy but can be implemented. The number of failure points in self-modifying instances should be reviewed.

Consider containerizing your application and using Compute Engine Container Optimized OS. Cloud Build can build your container and do a rolling MIG instance update. COS will then pull down the latest image on start.